# How to open the Google play app from a shared Facebook link?

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent

My app can share a link on Facebook, but the shared link opens Google play on the browser, not the Google play app directly. This get more difficult for the user and will  not generate much downloads. How can I get the shared link to open the Google play app instead of the browser?

I assume that the correct intent has to be created with

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
```

It has to be started with

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
```

The problem is how to set the information in the intent(the code between creating the intent and starting it).I used this code before and it started the web page for the app without problems:

```
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Product name");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=example.package");
```

I try to replace this with the following code, which should start Google play:

```
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Product name");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Uri.parse("market://details?id=example.package"));
```

This results in that the link to the appstore is not included when I try to share the link from Facebook. I test with 2 different devices, which both have Google play. I also try with

```
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Product name");
sharingIntent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=example.package"));
```

This resulted in the error message "can not find the application to perform this action". Do you know how I can solve this problem? I have replaced the package name of my app with an example package in this thread, but I am using the correct package name when I am testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are following [this guide](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/promote/linking.html) to decide how to format your intents.

What i see is that you are using Uri.parse when using the "market://" scheme.

```
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Uri.parse("market://details?id=example.package"));
```

Note that `Uri.parse` is not returning a `String`, but an `URI` and when you want to share anything you have to send a `String` to a intent with the action `Intent.ACTION_SEND` such as you are doing with the play URL. The guide talks about `Uri.parse("market://` but with an intent with the action `Intent.ACTION_VIEW`, this is, to directly open the play app from the app that is creating the intent, and not for creating a link to be shared.

So, if you want to share a link to your app, you should share the link as you would do with a normal URL, as a String

```
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Product name");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "market://details?id=example.package");
```

And this way the link will be included in the content posted in Facebook. But know, we dont know what android devices will actually understand that scheme and open it, or even if facebook will post it as a link.

But, anyways. I think your mistake  is one step before: Why do you want to share a link to the play app page of your product? That could be ok if the user that see that link on facebook is using an android mobile, but what happens if the user is using a computer, of any other smartphone not running android? the will just have a broken link, and thats not useful at all.

and, as you can read in the linked guide,

> http://    Lets the user choose whether to launch the Play Store app
>   or the browser to handle the request. If the browser handles the
>   request, it loads the target page on the Google Play web site.

So when opening from a android device, the user will be able to choose how to open it.

**So, what i would do for sure is to share a link to the google play website.**

Comment: You are probably right that it is better to share the link to the Google play website. The problem is that the shared link opens the browser on both of my devices. I have probably set the browser to be opened as default some time. I want to change this, so the Google Play app is opened by default, but I don't find any such option in the settings. Do you know where I can change this setting? I can't publish an app, which I haven't tested and proven to work like expected. That is why I need to see that the shared link opens Google play on my devices. I have S4 mini and Galaxy Tab2.

Comment: To clear the settings about the default activities that open an intent, you just need to now the package name of that default activity (I.e. your browser) and use the code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20132663/sending-ussd-code-programmatically-dials-skype-instead-of-normal-phone-call/20435472#20435472